# Why does mathematics say "quadratic" instead of "squaric"?

Tags: etymology, terminology, mathematics

In mathematics, powers of 2 and 3 are often referred to using "square" and "cube" terminology: a "number squared/cubed", the "square/cube root of a number".  But then you have "quadratic and cubic" Beziér curves.  Why is the confusing term "quadratic" used when "squaric" would be more consistent?  Alternatively, why isn't the term "hexatic" used instead of "cubic"?

Comment: Now there's a can of worms. Why "hexatic"? If we're looking at edges, wouldn't that be a pyramid and a cube "dodecic"? Vertices? Then you get a quadratic pyramid and an octic cube. And would a square be two or three dimensional? "Two faced squares" sounds a bit Kerouac to me...

Comment: The Latin for *square* was "quadra" and later "quadratus", and for cube was "cubus" so *quadratic* and *cubic* are reasonably consistent in their English etymology (there are steps through Old French)

Comment: Fun fact: in German, equations/polynomials can be "quadratisch" or "kubisch". so, the same as English. But while a square is a "Quadrat", and there isn't really an alternative word, noone outside math would call a cube a "Kubus", everyone uses "Würfel" ("dice").

Comment: In a lot of modern (and dead!) European languages square is some form of "quadrat"

Comment: To make matters worse, a less well-known form is called the [quadric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric), which is a polynomial in any number of variables with degree 2.

Comment: This question and its answers make me ecstatic.

Comment: Your concern is entirely backwards; your question should be why the word "square" exists in the first place to describe a specifically parameterized quadrilateral, where the concept came from and what purpose it solves that "quadrilateral" doesn't already solve, not why "quadratic" and "quadrilateral" are words.

Comment: By the way, to answer my own hypothetical question (`why does the word "square" exist when quadrilateral already covers it?`): It is from the Old French `esquarrer`, which was a stone cutting term to mean "to cut a block into an equilateral quadrilateral"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is an old usage:

***Quadratic:***

> 1650s, "[square](https://www.etymonline.com/word/quadratic)," with -ic + obsolete quadrate "a square; a group of four things" (late 14c.), from Latin quadratum, noun use of neuter adjective quadratus "square, squared," past participle of quadrare "to square, make square.

(Etymonline)

[Terms of Latin origin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_influence_in_English) were often adopted in the 16th/17th c.

> “During the English Renaissance, from around 1500–1650, some 10,000 to 12,000 words entered the English lexicon, including the word lexicon. Many of these words were borrowed directly from Latin, both in its classical and medieval forms. In turn, Late Latin also included borrowings from Greek.

(Wikipedia)

Note that also  ***[squaric](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaric_acid#:%7E:text=Squaric%20acid%2C%20also%20called%20quadratic,Squaric%20acid)*** is used but with the following sense:

> ***Squaric acid, also called quadratic acid*** because its four carbon atoms approximately form a square, is a diprotic organic acid with the chemical formula C4O2(OH)2.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: So mathematics actually went from consistent terminology to inconsistent terminology?  lol

Comment: @Jez      Not math, the English language adopted this terminology. In the 17th century Latin terms were sort of fashionable in English.

Comment: Lots and lots of terms in maths are nonsensical unless you know the definition (or to put it positively, they only make any kind of sense along with their definition). Take all terms based on names of their inventors/proponents ("Abelian Group", "Hilbert Space" etc.). Totally inconsistent and nonsensical. This is nothing particularly fancy or lol-worthy, it's just the way it is. @Jez

Comment: @Jez Inconsistent mixing of terms from Latin/French and Saxon origin is a pervading universal trait of English. Why do you say "eye" but "ocular"?

Comment: @AnoE: There's also the fact that some mathematicians were rather prolific and consequently have [rather a lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_things_named_after_Leonhard_Euler) of things named after them.

Comment: Imagine having to come up with a consistent "domain" name for all these Euler's XYZ things... :) a nightmare... @kevin

Answer (score 15):

Simple answer: *quadra-* is a Latin root meaning "square". (And *cub-* is a Latin root meaning... "cube".)

So it is consistent—give or take using Latin roots.

Comment: The point I made is that "cubic" is then used which refers to the shape and not the number of sides, which is inconsistent with "quadratic".

Comment: @Jez: "Quadratic" refers to the shape, and "cubic" refers to the shape. They're both the Latin names for the shapes. I'm not quite sure what's inconsistent?

Comment: Quadratic refers to the number of sides, not the shape.  The equivalent for cubic would be "hexatic".

Comment: @Jez: No, it just happens that the Latin word for "square" derives from the word for "four", but the Latin word for "cube" doesn't happen to derive from a number. I'm not sure where "hexatic" comes in - that would presumably derive from the Greek word for "six", but having a Latin word for the 2 case and a Greek one for the 3 case doesn't seem any more consistent to me!

Comment: Well, the Latin equivalent would be "sexatic" or something, I guess.  The point is that we talk about a "square root" of a number.  Using the term "square" in one place and "quadratic" in another is inconsistent.

Comment: @Jez: "sextic" is a word, and it's used for equations with x^6. The equivalent for x^4 is "quartic". Using an "English" word in one context, and a Latin/Greek-derived word in another--but referring to the same thing--is very common (eg we speak with a "voice" but the study of that is "phonology" (*phon-* being Greek for "voice")). (I put "English" in quotes because, in fact, both "square" and "voice" derive, indirectly, from their Latin equivalents...)

Comment: Right, but in this case the two different-derived terminologies are used in the same context: quadratic curves, cubic curves.  In different contexts I could understand it but in this same context I find it quite grating.

Comment: @Jez: I'm not sure which terminologies you're talking about? As I've said, "quadratic" and "cubic" are derived exactly the same - both come from the Latin words for the corresponding shapes (square and cube, respectively). So that's consistent, right?

Comment: And the fact that squares and cubes are common, but equivalent four-dimensional shapes are not, indicates why quartic, quintic, etc, are used for 4th powers and above. Maybe if there was a common Latin word for a tesseract (which incidentally comes from Greek), there would be a different term for the fourth power. I guess the OP also complains that they are in second place not twoth.

Comment: @psmears "Quadratic" and "cubic" are both derived from Latin, however, "quadratic" and "square" appear to be roughly derived from the same place.  What I'm complaining about is the fact that different derivations are used for the squared form in different contexts (a number squared, a quadratic equation) but the same derivation is used for the cubed form (a number cubed, a cubic equation).  It'd be less confuding if the same derivation were used in all places for the squared form too.

Comment: @Jez:You seem to keep changing what you're complaining about. Yes, we use the "English" words (square/cube) in one context--when raising to a power--and the Latinate words (quadratic/cubic) in another context--talking about the degree of an equation. Yes, it happens that (a) the "English" words both derive from the Latin ones, and (b) the ones for cube happen to be the same. But as I've already mentioned--it's very common to use an "English" word in one context and a Latin-based one in another; this is just an example of that. It's no more inconsistent than the rest of the English language :)

Comment: @Jez If this bothers you that much, you're going to have a rough time of it studying mathematics. There have been many questions like this about terminology in math.stackexchange, and the answer is usually that it's based on history and convention. Just like it is here.

Comment: @Jez 2^2 is two squared, 2^3 is two cubed, but we don't say that 2^4 is two "hypercubed". We could, but we don't. When dealing with powers, 2 and 3 have nicknames that other numbers don't - and these nicknames are in no way forced to only use the same word, because humans give names based on what _sounds_ right. Quadratic still refers to a square, so there _is_ consistency in calling ^2 a "square". It's just that there is more than one word for "square" and you clearly don't like using both of them even though the vast majority of mathematicians see no issue with that.

Comment: @Jez: I suppose there's a counter-complaint about why the perfectly fine Latin word _quadrus_ was corrupted late into _exquadra_, then that corrupted by French into _esquire_, and then that corrupted by the English into this new-wave _square_. C'mon people, just stick with standard nomenclature. :-P https://www.etymonline.com/word/square

Comment: @DavidK Thankfully, I don't have to study mathematics, much.  Although as a developer I have some interaction with things like Bézier curves.  It doesn't come at all naturally though.  If I had to make a living through mathematics I think I'd be broke.  :-)

Comment: @Jez As someone who develops software for a living, I found it the other way around -- the language of math was easy to understand, while the jargon of software and operating systems initially seemed illogical. But one learns through usage, just as we learn all the crazy rules of English that we sometimes don't even know we know.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest that your question is backwards. Rather than asking "why is the word quadratic used", you might astutely inquire "why is the word square in use?"

In Old French,`esquarrer` was a term meaning "to cut a block of stone into an equilateral quadrilateral."

As others have suggested, `quadra` is from the Latin word for "four" (`quattuor`) but the French invaded the British Island from Normandy because they caught wind that Harolð Harðráði had taken wine to a dinner party.

Then they brought their Frenchy-French Frenchiness into the mix and now we have the word "square" because they wanted to cut stones into cubes.

Comment: Random, useless knowledge to add since we're talking about Latin numbers: if you ever wonder why some people pronounce the number 101 in word form as "one hundred and one" I point you to the Latin for the number: `centum et unus` ...God bless the Romans; terrific.

Comment: Wait, is there another widely used formal way to say 101?! I'm pretty sure my dialect only has "a hundred and one" and "one hundred and one," which is also found in titles like *One Hundred and One Dalmatians* and *One Thousand and One Nights*.

Comment: @Vectornaut in American English, teachers instruct that introducing the word "and" into the pronunciation of a number is improper. "One hundred and twenty seven" is instructed to be read "One hundred twenty seven." The special distinction I mentioned exists for the number "One hundred and one"  being that it is `centum et unus` in Latin, but English teachers tend towards overenforcement of the "inappropriate 'and' rule" teaching it instead as "one hundred one."

Comment: Weird—I don't recall ever hearing a teacher say that! I'd love to know where and when you've encountered it. I went to school in the Midwest in the 1990s–2000s.

Comment: I never thought to investigate how I use "and" in three-digit numbers; it's more complicated than I expected! I've found some examples (101, 105, 112, 117, 180) where the "and" feels almost obligatory to me, although it sometimes seems to drop if I speak very quickly. I've also found examples (365, 542) where the "and" seems optional, and tends to be absent or very clipped by default. There are even a few (156, 256, 756) where the "and" seems distinctly disfavored. I'm guessing that prosody drives a lot of the variation.

Comment: @Vectornaut Midwest 1980s and 1990s. Great grandfather (1901-1995) was a teacher, principal, and superintendent.  You'll encounter the rule most prominently in the writing of the amounts on checks.

Comment: Interesting! Maybe the teaching practice you mention fell out of favor very quickly during the 1990s? I guess it's also possible that it varies a lot from teacher teacher, and I missed it by sheer luck. I'm pretty sure I do always leave out the "and" when writing checks, but I don't know whether I was ever told explicitly to do that.